# How can I combine axios, swr and header config in the code below?

Tags: reactjs, swr, use-swr

in **windows 10** , i'm using **react-router-dom 5.2.0** and **react-redux 7.2.5** and **react 17.0.2** and **axios 0.21.4** and **WebStorm 2023.1.3** IDE and **PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2** and **djangorestframework==3.14.0** and **Django==4.2.4** and **djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.0**.

**Note:** How can I combine `swr` with `axios` and its **header config** in the code below in the **post method** request through an `api` to the Django backend?

**Consider:**

```
 const config = {
                    header: { 
                        'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    }
                }
 const {data} = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/register/', {'name':name,'family':family,'email':email,'password':password,config);
```

**Note :** Please help me to implement a plan in the answer, considering that the plan is like this

**Consider:**

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/user/123', fetcher)
```

link for help : [enter link description here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started)

*Please help me with your ideas, I hope I don't make a typo... because I really didn't find a correct answer in the forums that would make me unnecessary.*

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like this:

```
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
     headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
     }
   })

  const fetcher = url => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)

  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/data', fetcher)
```